# Removing a block of a certain character in pure bash

Tags: bash

Hey so lets say you have a string "aabbaabbbaab". As you can see you have 3 blocks of "b". For example, how do I remove the 2nd block of b , so "bbb"? It should turn the string into: "aabbaaaab". I have tried looking everywhere but I just couldnt think of a right syntax for my specific question. I need to do this in pure bash so no awk, sed etc.

Comment: In case you change your mind about the "no sed" requirement, here was my GNU sed answer : `sed 's/b\+//2'`

Comment: @Aaron Hey if I eventually can't figure out how to do this without sed I will use your approach thanks.

Comment: Why no sed or awk? These are POSIX tools and are 99.999% likely to be present wherever BASH is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's pure bash: it iterates over the string, character by character. When it detects it's in the n'th block of the specified char, we know that the entire string up til here is the first part of the output we want. When we get to the end of the n'th block, we know that the rest of the string is wanted.

```
remove_nth_block () {
    local str=$1 char=$2 n=$3
    local i count=0 prev prefix
    for ((i=0; i<${#str}; i++)); do
        if [[ ${str:i:1} = $char && $prev != $char ]]; then
            ((++count == n)) && prefix=${str:0:i}
        else
            if [[ ${str:i:1} != $char && $prev = $char && $count -eq $n ]]; then
                echo "$prefix${str:i}"
                return
            fi
        fi
        prev=${str:i:1}
    done
}
```

Then

```
$ remove_nth_block aabbaabbbaab b 2
aabbaaaab
$ remove_nth_block aabbaabbbaab a 2
aabbbbbaab
```

Comment: Congrats, I had tried to do a similar solution and abandoned it in frustration. `bash` isn't such a great language without its diverse toolbox

Comment: And it's really slow too.

Answer (score 1):

This should print `myString` after replacing all occurrences of `bbb` with nothing. For some really useful tips and examples of string manipulation in bash, check out [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) site.

```
myString="aabbaabbbaab"
echo ${myString//bbb/}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I should have been more specific. I need to be able to find the Nth block based on user input. For example if I type in "bb" it means i need to find the 2nd block of b and remove that block.